# Strongly typed dataset modification breaks binding

Tags: c#

I'm building a winform app which uses datagrids, lists, textboxes which are bound to columns in a strongly typed dataset which is part of my project. I am having issues when I want to add an extra column at design time to one of the tables in the dataset where once I've added it and then save it, then my winform loses bindingsource's and individual controls which relied on the particular binding source being lost having there bound data source definitions lost.

The datatable I am modifying does not have any relationship to the table that is used by the bindingsource which is being lost.

The reason why this is causing me a rpoblem is that I lose all bindings each time I make a change in the ataset and it becomes very cumbersome to redefine the bindings again and again just for one little change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I've seen a lot of buggy behavior from the Visual studio designer like this...hopefully someone else has a direct fix for you, but I've taken to moving my databindings manually to the constructor or OnLoad function:

```
txtAddress1.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "sAddress1");
cmbState.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", myBindingSource, "iStateID");
///etc...
```

That way it's under my control and not the designer's.  Not a solution to your problem, but at least a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Clyde, I wanted to avoid that in the beginning but then completely forgot about that approach. It achieves the effect I want and atleast it means less dependancy on Visual Studio for managing bindings for me.